# Blockchain adoption rate in industry?

Tags: blockchain

I understand that Blockchain is coming, it has lot of potential and its complex. What is its adoption rate in enterprises ? Is it only related to Authentication or Verification ?

Comment: the adoption rate is almost nil. it is even not used in as money, forget about authentication or verification.

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/28-of-businesses-experimenting-with-blockchain-but-almost-none-run-it-in-production/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is its adoption rate in enterprises?

It is still low. A lot of projects are in beta. 
Slowly and without a lot of noise, big enterprises are playing around decentralised (<< not only) blockchain technology. You can see a lot of things going on in banking area. There are jurisprudence and IoT projects as well.

There are many unrealistic ideas, many ico's that are just issuing the token to grab some money and not to finish their product. I am pointing out these facts, because you can easily get lost in all the stuff happening.

> Is it only related to Authentication or Verification?

Authentication and verification are like a fundamental parts of the blockchain. If we are talking about cases of application of blockchain consider the potential of smart contracts and definitely read [this short article](https://www.coindesk.com/information/applications-use-cases-blockchains/) with coverage of different areas.